# Cake routing breaking on windows server 2003 (%EF%BF%BD)

Tags: url, cakephp, windows-server-2003, backslash, apache2.2

Just uploaded an app to a box running windows server 2003.

Any route or link that is specified with a `/` in it becomes corrupt - a little black circle with a `?` appears in the link/address bar with the value of `%EF%BF%BD`

```
$this->Html->link('Home', '/home'); // produces the problem

$this->Html->link('Home', array('action'=>'home')); // does not
```

is there a fix? I'm not used to working on windows server; but it runs and displays and works fine on a CentOS box and my local machine (Win 7), so it would suggest it's incorrectly configured at the server end.

Comment: Are you running apache or iis?

Comment: apache 2.2.22 and wamp server stack

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `mod_rewrite` is configured properly and running: in the Apache config file the following line should be present and not commented:

```
LoadModule mod_rewrite modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

And see that you have `AllowOverride all` for the DocumentRoot

With Apache for Windows `mod_rewrite` is disabled by default and CakePHP needs it for handling fancy URLs.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but that all appears to be OK. I'll keep digging; perhaps it isn't server related after all.